# Lua program to clean up phone numbers

Tags: object-oriented, strings, lua

How idiomatic is my code? Since Lua does not have classical inheritance such as in OO languages. Feedback on the test and implementation are both appreciated/welcomed.

The rules are:

- If the phone number is less than 10 digits assume that it is bad number
- If the phone number is 10 digits assume that it is good
- If the phone number is 11 digits and the first number is 1, trim the 1 and use the first 10 digits
- If the phone number is 11 digits and the first number is not 1, then it is a bad number
- If the phone number is more than 11 digits assume that it is a bad number

---

```
local PhoneNumber = {}

function PhoneNumber:new(no_as_string)
  self.__index = self
  local n = "0000000000"
  n = no_as_string:gsub("[^0-9]", "")
  if (n:len() == 11 and n:sub(1, 1) == "1") then 
    n = n:sub(2, 11)
  else 
    if (n:len() > 10 or n:len() < 10) then
      n = "0000000000"
    end
  end
  return setmetatable({ number = n }, self)
end

function PhoneNumber:areaCode(symbol)
  return self.number:sub(1, 3)
end

function PhoneNumber:toString(symbol)
  return "("..self.number:sub(1, 3)..") "..self.number:sub(4, 6).."-"..self.number:sub(7, 10)
end

return PhoneNumber
```

Here is the test:

```
local PhoneNumber = require('phone-number')

describe("PhoneNumber()", function() 
  it("cleans the number (123) 456-7890", function() 
    local phone = PhoneNumber:new("(123) 456-7890")
    assert.are.equals(phone.number,"1234567890")
  end)

  it("cleans numbers with dots", function()
    local phone = PhoneNumber:new("123.456.7890")
    assert.are.equals(phone.number,"1234567890")
  end)

  it("valid when 11 digits and first digit is 1", function()
    local phone = PhoneNumber:new("11234567890")
    assert.are.equals(phone.number,"1234567890")
  end)

  it("invalid when 11 digits", function()
    local phone = PhoneNumber:new("21234567890")
    assert.are.equals(phone.number,"0000000000")
  end)

  it("invalid when 9 digits", function()
    local phone = PhoneNumber:new("123456789")
    assert.are.equals(phone.number,"0000000000")
  end)

  it("has an area code", function()
    local phone = PhoneNumber:new("1234567890")
    assert.are.equals(phone:areaCode(),"123")
  end)

  it("formats a number", function()
    local phone = PhoneNumber:new("1234567890")
    assert.are.equals(phone:toString(),"(123) 456-7890")
  end)
end)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've **a lot** of unnecessary code. First off, [as janos stated](//codereview.stackexchange.com/a/70654/12240):

> ```
> local n = "0000000000"
> n = no_as_string:gsub("[^0-9]", "")
> ```
>
> The initialization of `n` is pointless here.

You can instead use just the lua pattern to match your input to desired result:

```
function PhoneNumber:new( Number )
    local n = string.gsub( Number, "%D", "" )
    n = n:match "^1?(%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d)$" or "0000000000"
    return setmetatable({ number = n, __index = self }, self)
end
```

Notice that I've changed the input argument to `Number` and later use `string.gsub( Number...`. This way; you've the advantage of inputting direct numbers and provide flexibility.

The pattern

```
"^1?(%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d)$"
```

is self-explanatory. In lua, if `string.match` failed to find any matched group; it returns `nil`. I've used this property to check for bad numbers.

---

Next thing I'd suggest that you do is store the number as an integer instead of string:

```
return setmetatable({ number = tonumber(n), __index = self }, self)
```

This is just because integers take less memory than strings. For retrieving area code etc., use mathematical operations:

```
function PhoneNumber:areaCode()  -- what was symbol parameter for?
    return math.floor( self.number / 10^7 )
end
```

---

Lastly, lua provides a meta-method: `__tostring` for conversion to strings from other types. Use it (It is the reason why I was able to use `string.gsub` above):

```
function PhoneNumber:__tostring()
    local f, n = math.floor, self.number
    local sFormat, iPart1, iPart2 = "(%d) %d-%d", f( n / 10^7 ), f( n / 10^3 % 10^4 )
    return sFormat:format( self:areaCode(), iPart1, iPart2 )
end
```

Now, instead of calling `PhoneObject:toString()`, you can do:

```
tostring( PhoneObject )
```

Comment: So many concepts explained. -I had been wondering how to use tostring in lua  - string.gsub vs string:gsub  - also the regex is sweet. -I did not even know abt the format function :)

Answer (score 3):

> ```
>   local n = "0000000000"
>   n = no_as_string:gsub("[^0-9]", "")
> ```

The initialization of `n` is pointless here. You should combine these two lines.

---

> ```
>   if (n:len() == 11 and n:sub(1, 1) == "1") then 
>     n = n:sub(2, 11)
>   else 
>     if (n:len() > 10 or n:len() < 10) then
>       n = "0000000000"
>     end
>   end
> ```

Using an `elseif` for the second `if` would reduce a level of nesting and be shorter and simpler.

---

> ```
>     if (n:len() > 10 or n:len() < 10) then
> ```

Instead of checking if len is bigger than 10 or smaller than 10, it would be simpler to check equality with 10. That would also eliminate one unnecessary call to `len()`. That is:

```
    if (n:len() != 10) then
```

---

> ```
> assert.are.equals(phone.number,"1234567890")
> ```

In unit testing, the convention in many languages is to put the *expected* value first, and the *actual* value second in assert statements. So I suggest to flip the arguments.